# Webpack 5 mini-css-extract-plugin dropping scss files

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, webpack-5, mini-css-extract-plugin

I am migrating a webpack config from webpack 4 and am trying to wire in the mini-css-extract-plugin.  However, all of my first party app CSS (SCSS) is not being injected into the main app.css file after extraction.  If I inspect the file received by the browser, I see the stubs where the css should be included, but it's not there.

[image]

You'll see above this line is a 3rd party CSS block that *is* included.

This is what my SCSS loader config looks like:

```
    {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // extract css into files
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader',
        }, {
          loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true, // <-- !!IMPORTANT!
            additionalData (source, loaderContext) {
              // All scss files ending with _library.scss
              // will not re-import additionalData
              if (loaderContext.resourcePath.endsWith('_library.scss')) {
                return source
              }

              // this is the first time, add the imports
              return '@use \'~@/assets/css/_library\';'
            }
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
          options: {
            resources: require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/assets/css/scssUtils.js'))
          }
        }]
      }
```

Anyone run into this issue before?  I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 0):

This was because of the block in the `additionalData` configuration.  My logic in there was incorrect, and basically returning an empty block instead of the content inside the file.

My solution was to eliminate it all together and just `@use _library.scss` in the files where it was appropriate, not every single scss file.